# Cider brewing, can I add pectolaze after fermentation started?

Tags: cider, pectic-enzyme

I'm making apple cider for the first time. I was careful about sanitizing, pasteurising, and adding campden, and I now have what seems to be nice fermentation in an airlocked demijohn.  I did not have pectolaze initially but now I got some.

Is it safe to add pectolaze at this point, or any time later, to reduce haziness? Would it have any effect on taste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was from clear juice it may not need it at all. From fruit then go for it.

Pectolase is fine to add at your stage but is better at the start of fermentation so the fermentation helps to keep it moving around, and the enzyme releases more trapped sugars so expect some more fermentation. You should be fine with some good swirling.

Comment: I started with full apples. I'll add the pectolaze and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Follow up: I added pectolaze about a week after fermentation stated, when bubbling has already slowed down significantly. I left it for another week before first racking. After second racking I got very clear (and good) cider.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off to leave the pectolase on the apples before adding the yeast as the yeast will break down the pectolase and reduce its effect.

But, you will be fine, I have added it after fermentation has begun before and suffer no ill effects.